# How to install Filmic Blender under Ubuntu?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, color, linux, color-management

I want to use the Filmic Blender color management. I'm not so advanced user, so I don't know where I missed something.
I renamed the filmic-blender to colormanagement and placed at the right place (I think): /usr/share/blender/2.78/datafiles. But when I open Blender, it still remains  with the standard color management...
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you sure blender is installed on that location? Did you install using a repository or did you download the file directly from blender.org? The color management folder belongs in the datafiles folder where the rest of the blender program files are.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's from Thomas Schiex ppa. The process did work in another machine. See my comment below.

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED!

Under Linux Ubuntu, the colormanagement folder is located here:

/usr/share/blender/2.78/datafiles.

To rename it, since it's a system folder, you must be logged in as administrator. It's easy. I opened Thunar file manager and navigated to the folder location. Once there, I right-clicked and chose "open terminal here". In the terminal, the command is:

sudo mv colormanagement colormanagement_oldbackup

Insert your root password and it's done.
To place the new folder in here, first place the "filmic-blender" folder on your home folder (in my case it's /home/gigabyte). Rename it as colormanagement. Then, open the terminal and type:

sudo cp -R /home/yourusername/colormanagement /usr/share/blender/2.78/datafiles

Insert again your password and it's done.
Remember that you doesn't need really type the whole lines. Use "Ctrl C" to copy from the file manager (right click on the folder/file and, and you'll see the label "location"). In the terminal use "Ctrl Shift V".

The Reluctant Computer

On the computer with Ubuntu 14, I had to allow Blender to access the new colormanagement folder. To do this, you must open the terminal on the folder "datafiles". Then, type:

sudo chown -R yourusername colormanagement

The system will ask for your password and it's done.

Ok, it's a little less easy than Windows, but what can I do? I love Ubuntu...

Comment: Note that you don't have to **install** blender necessarily. You can just download the files from blender.org and unzip them in a directory within your /home/user folder. That way you don't have to deal with permissions.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't have this tip. I guess this is the best solution to use Blender under Linux. Thanks!

Comment: The permission system is really cool and powerful, advanced and safe, but it gets reallly annoying at times

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't the right Folder and there is still a subfolder like filmic-blender-master in your colormanagement folder, in that case you had to move this to the datafiles and rename it.
If you have installed Filmic Blender you have to restart Blender and than change in the Properties tab under Scene under Color Management the Render: View to Filmic Log Encoding Base.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but nothing of this worked. However, it did works in another machine (see my comment).

Comment: News: in another machine, with Ubuntu 16, I tried the same process, and IT WORKS perfectly, with any problems. Weird...
But I noticed something: in the machine in which the process didn't work (Ubuntu 14), there are a suspicious "X" attached to the folder [link] (http://www.rlocatellidigital.com.br/fig1-printscreen-2017feb18.png). In the machine in which it did works [link] (http://www.rlocatellidigital.com.br/fig2-printscreen-2017feb18.png), there aren't this strange and misterious sign... (remember, I'm not so advanced Linux user).

Comment: Your Pictures are not working.

Comment: Wierd... is working for me. Anyway, I placed them on dropbox: [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/itghd3zop7x82l7/fig1-printscreen-2017feb18.png?dl=0) [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqq34zzi6kvj9v6/fig2-printscreen-2017feb18.png?dl=0)